# Activerecord errror after upgrading from rails 3.0.0 to 3.0.11 - table doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-3-upgrade

I upgraded from rails 3.0.0 to 3.0.11 (don't want to move to 3.1 yet, for various reasons)

I changed the following in my Gemfile:

```
-gem 'rails', '3.0.0'
-gem 'mysql2', "0.2.6"
+gem 'rails', '3.0.11'
+gem 'mysql2', "~>0.2.7"
```

Fired up console and tried:

```
 PopularMedia.where(:media_type => 1).all
```

and got this:

```
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'matcha_development.popular_media' doesn't exist: SELECT `popular_media`.* FROM `popular_media` WHERE `popular_media`.`id` = 1
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mysql2-0.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:265:in `query'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mysql2-0.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:265:in `block in execute'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:202:in `block in log'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.11/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:200:in `log'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mysql2-0.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:265:in `execute'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mysql2-0.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:586:in `select'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:7:in `select_all'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:56:in `select_all'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.11/lib/active_record/base.rb:473:in `find_by_sql'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.11/lib/active_record/relation.rb:64:in `to_a'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.11/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:143:in `all'
from (irb):2
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Worked fine before, so what could possibly be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

When I have issues like these, what I usually do is make a new project using the newer rails gem.  This way, I can look at the Gemfile that is produced and compare it to the old one that I have and then proceed to update it accordingly.

Also, be sure to run bundle install after changing anything in your Gemfile.

If you forget, it can usually be the reason you are having the problem.

I hope that helps you fix your issue.